# iAd appears before it is loaded in iOS using subviews

Tags: ios, ads, subview

Hello I have an issue where my ads appear before they are even loaded.

I got this

```
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

- (AppDelegate *) appdelegate {
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //this part set alpha 0 does nothing
    [_UIiAD setAlpha:0];
    _UIiAD = [[self appdelegate] UIiAD];
    _UIiAD.delegate = self;

    [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0,470,320,50)];
    [self.view addSubview:_UIiAD];
    }

    -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"ads loaded");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [_UIiAD setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"ads not loaded");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [_UIiAD setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I have tried to stick

```
[_UIiAD setAlpha:0];
```

In various parts of my code, but still same issue.

Comment: Well right now [_UIiAD setAlpha:0]; is definitely in the wrong place because you're setting it before even initializing _UIiAD.

Answer (score 0):

If your AdBannerView has been initialized outside of this snippet (presumably in AppDelegate from what you show in your `viewWillAppear:` code), it can still load ads even before it has a delegate.

Instead of programmatically adding the iAd banner as a subview after creating it somewhere else, have you tried adding it using Interface Builder and just using the code to hide/unhide based on whether or not it's received content.